# API usage dilemma for my new Android App

Tags: android, android-camera, deprecated, application-design, camera-api

I am planning to develop a new Android app with a camera use case in it. Reading the API documentation it seems like Android's 'Camera.hardware' class has been deprecated and new 'android.hardware.camera2' has been introduced. So my question is should which API should I start making my app with? Is it a good idea to start developing my app with the deprecated API, so in that case at least I am not restricted to just Android L? And then later once I get good traction, use the new Camera APIs. Will the old APIs work for Android L too ? What would be a good strategy?

Answer (score 0):

The old `android.hardware.Camera` is deprecated, this means that it still works (i've tryed it) but there are new API that works better.

However Camera probably has everything you need, so I would recommend to use it because you will have compatibility with every android version.

Answer (score 0):

When let's say an Object is deprecated,doesn't mean it's not going to work in your app.